# Fuzzy Match of a column with respect to position of strings

Tags: python, fuzzy-search

How do we find the Fuzzy Match of a column with itself in Python?

For example: ABC12340 and ABC12304 -> it shows a score of 90 (with `fuzz.ratio`)
ABC12340 and ABC12350 -> it shows a score of 90 (with `fuzz.ratio`)

```
fuzz.ratio('ABC12340', 'ABC12304') -\> 90
fuzz.ratio('ABC12340', 'ABC12350') -\>90
```

In the second case, the output of the function must have impact on the position of strings but it shows same score.

The reason why the position is important is that Company makes a small change in last few digits while renewing the contract.

Kindly suggest what function should I use.

Thanks in advance

I have tried :

```
fuzz.ratio('ABC12340', 'ABC12304') -\> 90
fuzz.ratio('ABC12340', 'ABC12350') -\>90
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this we can use a combination of fuzz.ratio and Jaccard similarity score. Jaccard Similarity score is simply the ratio of the intersection divided by the union. So for example, if 2 strings have the same characters but the position is different the `1-fuzz.ratio` will give you the dissimilarity score between those 2 strings. And, if 2 strings have different characters `1-Jaccard score` would give the dissimilarity score between those 2 strings. And if Both position and characters are different we will use the max of both scores to quantify the dissimilarity.

```
def dissimilar_score(s1, s2):
    a = set(s1)
    b = set(s2)
    jacccard_score =  1 - len(a.intersection(b)) / len(a.union(b))
    fuzz_ratio = (100 - fuzz.ratio(s1,s2))/100
    return max(jacccard_score, fuzz_ratio)

>>> print(dissimilar_score('ABC12340', 'ABC12304'), dissimilar_score('ABC12340', 'ABC12350'))
>>> (0.12, 0.2222222222222222)
```

Comment: But how can we use the same for dataframe columns?

Comment: If you want to apply it to a column of a data frame, Then you need to create a pairwise matrix with the dissimilar_score as the values, and all the words of the column as both row and column of this pairwise matrix

Comment: In the below example,
print(dissimilar_score('ABC1902121', 'ABC1902211')) --> 0.1

print(dissimilar_score('ABC2001350', 'ABC2001340')) --> 0.22
In the first example, 2 digits are changing their position i.e 1 and 2 are changing their positions
But in 2nd example, only one digit is changing its position i.e 5 and 4 , Then why is the dissimilar score more in the 2nd example?

Comment: In the 1st example the dissimilar score is less because we can obtain ABC1902121 from ABC1902211 just by doing one operation that is removing 2  and inserting it between 11, Since it takes only one operation the fuzz.ratio is high. I suggest that if only your last four digits of the string change, don't use fuzzy ratio. You can just use the difference between those last 4 digits as a metric.